# Only show tooltip when an element has a title attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to display the jQuery tooltip ONLY when the dom contains a title.
For example: I want to tooltip a button. If the button has a title attribute **then display** the tooltip. If the button doesn't have a title attribute then **don't display** the tooltip.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you share some code?

Answer (score 3):

Could probably just check for the title attribute in the usual way, no?

```
$('a[title]').tooltip();
```

Comment: This could be exactly what I was looking for. I just couldn't get it!

Thank you very much!